# What data structure does a `contenteditable` div use to store its text?

Tags: html, data-structures, browser

As far as I know, the predominant data structures used by text editors are [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) and [gap buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer), though [there are others](http://www.finseth.com/craft/).

Does an HTML div with `contenteditable="true"` use any of them to store its data, or does it naively hold it in a string, recreating it when the user makes a change?

Comment: it doesn‘t store anything. it manipulates its contained DOM-elements. Try innerHTML to get the contents

Comment: @Psi The browser has to keep state _somehow_, right? So, a div has `innerHTML`, and when you write to it, the corresponding JS object's string is recreated with the new data (since strings are immutable in JS). In other words, a naive implementation. Is that correct?

Comment: when you write to `innerHTML`, it’s going to be _parsed_ into DOM-elements. That’s correct so far. But it’s more than just storing data. It‘s a complete rebuild of the DOM and re-rendering